# Getting Domain for User with DSQuery | DSGet

Tags: batch-file, active-directory, dsquery

Using DSQuery and DSGet to get user attributes that are needed to make accounts (not associated with their Windows account). The current command I've got is:

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectclass=User)(mail=first.last@email.com))" | dsget user -samid -fn -ln -office -email > user.txt
```

which gets me all the information I need except the domain the user is associated with. There's the attribute in AD called `User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)` (first box), but as far as I can tell DSGet doesn't return that. I know the DSQuery can get me the groups the user is in but I'm not sure if there's an easy (one-liner) that can get the info needed.  Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Comment: The domain name (in DNS format) is part of user's DN. Are you looking for anything particular?

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute **User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)** in Attribute Editor so there is another way we can get the user logon name using distinguish name (DN) and UPN(User logon Name)
[image]

please use the below command to get the DN

**This is for user**

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectclass=user)(mail=first.last@microsoft.com))" | dsget user "CN=RahulShaw,CN=Users,DC=microsoft,DC=com" -samid -fn -ln -office -email -DN -UPN > Ansuman.txt
```

[image]

**This is under Domain Users**

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=Group)(objectclass=group)(mail=first.last@microsoft.com))" | dsget group "CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=microsoft,DC=com" -samid -DN > ipsita.txt
```

[image]